# Instancing with a THREE.SkinnedMesh

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to render many skinned meshes in a scene and animate each one independently of one another.

I know you can make different meshes reference the same geometry data/attributes in the shader. I'm wondering if it's possible to do instancing with a Skinned Mesh. Meshes can share vertex data, but can they also share bone data? I'm guessing that if the animation takes place in the vertex shader it would be possible, but if it takes place on the CPU then it wouldn't be.